# Could using gets() on an empty char array cause memory problems?

Tags: c, clang

The code below works, but I am assigning an empty string to a char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[ ]= "";
  gets(a);
  printf("You entered: %s", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Then gets(a), fills it up with whatever the user inputs no matter how long the string is, but if no size is given. Am I at risk of overwriting things in memory ? I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to C and I'm worried that I'm doing something wreckless with this code, since all documentation on the gets() function uses a string with predefined length such as char a[10].

Comment: You can't `gets()` into a zero-length buffer. Also don't use `gets()`. At least use `fgets()`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the particular flavor of `gets` you're using here was considered dangerous enough that is was _removed_ from C in C11 and from C++ in C++14.

Comment: You cannot have a zero-length array, at least not without engaging a language extension.  Your example does not do that, and it does not contain a zero-length array (as declared, array `a` has length 1, as needed to accommodate the terminator of an "empty" string).

Comment: `char a[] = ""` does have predefined length and that length is `1`

Answer (score 4):

> Could using gets() on an empty char array cause memory problems?

Yes, most definitely.

To also answer a couple additional questions:

> Could using gets() on **any** char array cause memory problems?

Yes, most definitely.

> Could using gets() cause memory problems?

Yes, most definitely.

> Could using gets

Ah! Stop right there.

***NEVER use `gets()`***. There is no way to use `gets()` without introducing potential memory problems in your programs. It is unsafe by design.

Comment: Re “There is no way to use `gets()` without introducing a memory problem in your programs”: This is not true. `gets` can be used with a trusted partner, such as a pipe from a cooperating process controlled by the same user. Not every program lies on the security perimeter. By analogy, programs that perform authentication using an external database (as of users and password information) must rely on data outside the program to be correct. That is not a design flaw; it simply means the security perimeter must enclose the necessary components.

Comment: @EricPostpischil true, I shall throw a "potential" in there. That is a slippery slope of an argument, which I would have expanded on had OP tagged this with [security] or related tags.

Answer (score 3):

`gets` is an unsafe function of getting input.

What you have described here is known as a `Buffer Overflow` vulnerability, and could potentially be used by an attacker with malicious intent to execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 1):

We were all learning at some point. Generally, gets() is not used because of that exact reason. We tend to use fgets() which you can define how much the function receives from input to avoid any memory problems assuming you don't accept too much.

Here a link for some example code. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gets-is-risky-to-use/

Comment: thanks for the link, this helped me a lot in my project. I can move forward with this knowing how to avoid buffer-overflow.